# In CoronaSDK, how can I handle a tap event from a hidden displayObject?

Tags: lua, coronasdk, displayobject

I am displaying a single png image on screen which contains various levels that the player can tap on.
I create the image using:

```
local levelsImage = display.newImage("assets/levelmap-levels.png", 0, 0, true)
```

I then overlap circles on top of each level as follows (*levels* is a table containing coordinates and tap radius for each level):

```
for i,level in ipairs(levels) do
    local levelTapCircle = display.newCircle(level.x, level.y, level.tapRadius)
    levelTapCircle.level=level -- attach the level info to the object so we know which level was tapped
    levelTapCircle.alpha=0.3
    myGroup:insert(levelTapCircle)
end
```

Attach the tap event handler as follows

```
levelTapCircle:addEventListener("tap", levelTapped)
```

In the levelTapped function I simply print the tap coordinates to the output console to prove that the event handler was invoked.

If the circles are visible (i.e. when alpha>0), then the event is raised and the levelTapped function is called.  However, if I change the alpha value to 0 in order to hide the circles, the tap event is not called.

```
levelTapCircle.alpha=0
```

The following can also be used to hide the circles, but it also results in the tap event handler not being invoked:

```
levelTapCircle.isVisible = false
```

**My question is:**

Is it possible to receive tap events from hidden displayObjects (circles in this case)? 
If not, how can I receive tap events from specific circular areas on the image, but without actually displaying the circles?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As was said, if alpha = 0 or isVisible = false, touch events will be disabled.

You can, however, stop this from happening with isHitTestable = true. This keeps you from having to use any sort of workaround.

```
object.alpha = 0
-- OR --
object.isVisible = false

-- Enable Touch/Tap Events With --
object.isHitTestable = true
```

Comment: I have tested this and it works.  I prefer to not have to use a workaround, so thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you set `alpha=0` or `isVisible=false` then tap and touch function are also disabled.

In two method you can handle this issue,

First one `levelTapCircle:setFillColor(255,255,255,0)`

or

```
levelTapCircle.alpha=0.01
```

Comment: I have tested both suggested solutions and both work.  Setting the alpha to a very small value like 0.01 makes the displayObject appear completely invisible and yet still receive tap events.